# How can I send a text message to a group that has more than 10 contacts in it?

Tags: sms

I made a group that has around 18 contacts. I wanted to send a text message to everyone. When I was prompted to select contacts from the group, it would not let me select more than 10. Anyone know how I can get around that limitation? I have a Samsung Infuse.

Comment: This is generally limited to prevent easy spam methods. I would think you'd need a different SMS app.

Comment: Try Goggle Messenger app for texting.

Answer (score 5):

[Handcent](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms&feature=search_result) should let you send more than 10 messages at once.  It has a nice interface for selecting multiple contacts too.  I haven't tested this (I don't want to send 10+ people a random text :) ).

Comment: I tried out Handcent by sending to a group of more than 75 people and it worked without a hitch

Answer (score 2):

If you are constantly sending group messages you may want to check out some of the Group apps for Android.

GroupMe - creates an independent phone number for the group to text for those without data. - https://market.android.com/details?id=com.groupme.android&feature=search_result

Disco - a google owned or backed group messaging app - https://market.android.com/details?id=com.disco.android&feature=search_result