# Set up an automated SMS server with Android (and a computer)?

Tags: sms, automation, gateway

I'm looking for a way to set up an SMS server (I don't know if there is better terminology for this, but probably).

What I want:

- use the phone as an SMS gateway for an automated server
- let the phone send and receive messages
- use a computer to command the phone what to do

Specific example use case: The phone gets an SMS message `[family] The party today will start at 2pm.` Which the computer will interpret and will order the phone to send the message over to all the numbers the computer has in the `family` list. Or f.e. `[add]family,0123456789` to let it add numbers to lists.

So what do I exactly need?

An app that can send all it's incoming messages to an HTTP server and can receive orders from that same server. Of course USB would be a better method than HTTP because it's safer.

Comment: Have a look at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14814/forward-sms-messages-to-http-interface and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/how-do-i-send-sms-from-pc-through-android-phone-or-to-android-phone

Comment: You might also get some ideas from [Forwarding text messages from an android phone to a TCP port of a PC](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24775/forwarding-text-messages-from-an-android-phone-to-a-tcp-port-of-a-pc/) and [How can I send a text message to a group that has more than 10 contacts in it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10043/how-can-i-send-a-text-message-to-a-group-that-has-more-than-10-contacts-in-it?rq=1)

Comment: My question wasn't related to sending messages to groups of people that were just examples. I could f.e. also use it to put events in a Calendar or to do domotics. None of the answers had solutions that worked in both ways. Except for one: the app SMS Gateway can port all SMS traffic to a SMTP/POP mail server in both ways. That can do the trick I think :)

Comment: I'm positive that this can be done via Tasker.

Comment: Can Tasker handle incoming HTTP requests? I never used the app but I know it's an extremely popular one...